# How to get for loop data outside for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I want the loop data out side forloop, but i'm getting only one value

```
<form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

               <select name="test[]"  multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="test">test</option>
                    <option value="mytesting">mytesting</option>
                    <option value="testingvalue">testingvalue</option>
                    </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
                   </form>


<?php
    $test=$_POST['test'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++)
    {
    $tyy = $test[$i];
    }


?>
```

I want to get $tyy out side for loop

I want the loop data out side forloop by i am getting only one value

Comment: Why would you need a third variable? You already have all the information available in `$_POST` *and* `$test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$tyy[] = $test[$i];
```

or you can concat the values by using this

```
$tyy = "";
for($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++)
    {
    $tyy .= $test[$i];
    }

print_r($tyy)
```

Comment: and one thing i have  a problem for this can you solve We have a multiple select drop down but i am not getting drop like we keep for single drop 


here the code

    <select multiple>
    <option>test</option>
    <option>test1</option>
    <option>test1</option>
    </select>


    <select>
        <option>test</option>
        <option>test1</option>
        <option>test1</option>
        </select>

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple check this link

Comment: i want http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select like this for multiple

Comment: so what was prob in that ?

Comment: dropdown is not getting like single select dropdown for multiple

Comment: you are getting drop down in http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select but i want same drop drop down for this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple   for multiple we are not getting drop down right so i want the drop like single drop down

Comment: will u make it as question ?

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
    $groupStr = "";
    for($i=0; $i< count($test); $i++)
        {
        $groupStr .= $test[$i];
        }

echo $groupStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is, because you are reassigning it every iteration. So change the line to this:

```
$tyy[] = $test[$i];
  //^^ See here, Now you are assign the value to a new array element every iteration
```

So that you have an array which you can use later

**Side Note:**

1. You know that you already have an array with this data in `$test` ? But if you want all data as one string you can use this (without a for loop):

```
$tyy = implode(", ", $test);
```

2. `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` is just a reflection of your URL, so this is open for XSS. You can use this to make it save:

```
<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8"); ?>
```

Comment: if i print echo $tty; outside for loop i am getting output array

Comment: @deb *output array* Do you mean you get `array` as output or what I guess you get Array to string? Also you know that you already have a array with it: `$test` is the same as you would have in `$tyy`

Comment: @deb do `print_r($tty);`

Answer (score 0):

Use $tyy as an array and fill that array in for loop by using array_push method.

```
 $tyy = array();

 $test=$_POST['test'];
for($i=0;$i<count($test);$i++)
{
   array_push($tyy, $test[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created one single variable, which is being overwritten each time you loop, so there is only one value to get.

If you want to access all the values, you need to save into an array instead of a single variable, or append all the values into one value

either

```
//create an array of values in $tyy
$tyy = $_POST['test'];
//you can now access $tyy by looping through it.
```

or

```
$test = $_POST['test'];
$for($i = 0; $i<count($test); $i++)
{
  //list all the values with commas separating them.
  $tyy .= $test[$i].", ";
}

//view the contents by echoing it.
echo $tyy;
```

Answer (score -1):

But why are you use loop for post data.
Your $_POST['test']  is self array so you can use it without for loop.
$array =  $_POST['test'];
try this.